# Xcode 10 Error: Multiple commands produce after generating NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a project to which I want to use CoreData. I first create the data model - the code compiles fine. Then, I try to generate the NSManagedObject subclasses by going to `Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass`. The generated files causes `Multiple commands produce` error when trying to compile.

Comment: Hi, I have this problem too. Did you get around this?

Comment: @rednaxela you have to manually code the class - generating it using Xcode creates the error.

Comment: Thanks so much for response. I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Since you've generated the NSManagedObject subclasses manually (by going to `Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass`), you need to tell CoreData that it shouldn't generate them again when building the project.

You do that by going to your data model file (something like `Model.xcdatamodeld`), and on the Data Model Inspector change `Codegen` from `Class Definition` to either   `Category/Extension` or (most probably) `Manual/None`:

[image]

*Note: You might have to delete your DerivedData after doing this.*

*See section "Xcode automatic subclass generation" at [What's New In Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017342-CH1-DontLinkElementID_7) for more information.*